# AWS S3 as an image storage for ios app using Web API

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-s3

I'm building a business solution that has an ios app backed up with Web API 2. I'm using AWS (Amazon Web Services) to host the API.

The ios app can take pictures. Pictures will be associated with a user in SQL Server. So I have a User table and Pictures table in my DB. I was thinking of using S3 to save the images. So how can I go about doing this? the ios app can upload the image to S3 but how can i relate the image to a user?

Answer (score 1):

You can either store the full s3 image url in your database and read the url from the db to then find the image on s3, or else use some sort of folder naming convention on s3 that would let you determine who's image file it is based on the filename along, i.e.:

```
/images/user/123/image1.jpg -> belongs to user 123
/images/user/123/image2.jpg -> belongs to user 123
/images/user/345/image1.jpg -> belongs to user 345
```

etc.